# Geolocation in real time on the web

Tags: android, asp.net, dictionary, geolocation

First I am not advanced programmer so be charitable ;) I need to create project which display on the map runner's way (in real time). Runner has android application (I've already create) which send latitude and longtitude. There's should be any API which checking new geolocation and another which displaying it on the map, am I right ?
I need to do this is ASP .NET, so any directions, links and tutorials will be very helpful.

Thanks 4 help

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you right, you already have the android application and now you need the server side in Asp.Net?

First you can have a look at the Asp.Net WebApi. Then you can create an API where you send the latitude and longitude from your Android application.

[ASP.Net WebAPI](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/tutorial-your-first-web-api)

After you have inserted the data into your database you have to fetch the data and visualize it in a map like Google Maps.
[Google Maps Javascript API Examples](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/)

Here I found a ASP.Net Google Maps tutorial (but I don't tried it myself):
[ASP.Net Google Maps Tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/291499/Google-Maps-API-V-for-ASP-NET)